# Need to parse string to DateTime

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ParseExact a string to DateTime fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428149/parseexact-a-string-to-datetime-fails)

I need to parse

> Oct 19 13:55

into a `DateTime` object.
Which culture would work for it ?

Comment: What about the year? You'll need a year to parse this to `datetime`

Comment: @Curt: Nope, by default it will use the current year.

Comment: What have you tried? In particular, have you tried specifying a custom format and using the invariant culture (as just one culture where "Oct" is a valid month abbreviation).

Comment: Perhaps not a specific culture, but use DateTime.ParseExact() specifying the appropriate custom format.

Comment: @JonSkeet `It ignores unrecognized data if possible and fills in missing month, day, and year information with the current date` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx You learn something everyday :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx).

Since your original string doesn't have the `year` information, it will consider the current year for the DateTime object.

```
string temp = "Oct 19 13:55";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(temp, "MMM dd HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

In `dt` you will get:

> dt = {19/10/2012 1:55:00 PM}

EDIT: 
Since the original data didn't contain date with a single digit day and hour, Following format may be tried for a date like:

```
Nov 8 1:44

DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(temp, "MMM d H:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

*(This would work for both the formats)*

Comment: It didnt work. only a single D and H should be there

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
string str="Oct 19  13:55";
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
bool ok = DateTime.TryParseExact((str == null ? "" : str.ToString().Trim()), "MMM dd  HH:mm", culture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
console.write(dt);
```