# ParseExact a string to DateTime fails

Tags: c#

```
Nov 8 1:44
```

When I use this code, it fails:

```
string DD = "Nov 8 1:44";

try
{
    DateTime.ParseExact(DD, "MMM dd HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Bad day because " + ex.Message);
}
```

It says,

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Please let me know where am I wrong.

Comment: Mistake number one is ignoring exceptions.

Comment: @JohnSaunders It was just a testing code, no worries. :)

Comment: If it doesn't matter, then please edit the code to remove the try/catch. If you're not attempting to demonstrate poor exception handling, then there's no reason to demonstrate exception handling at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That format would be

```
MMM d H:mm
```

per the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) you need a single `d` and `H` due to the fact that your source string is using a single digit day and hour.

> "d"
>
> The day of the month, from 1 through 31.
>
> More information: The "d" Custom Format Specifier.
>
> 6/1/2009 1:45:30 PM -> 1
>
> 6/15/2009 1:45:30 PM -> 15

---

> "dd"
>
> The day of the month, from 01 through 31.
>
> More information: The "dd" Custom Format Specifier.
>
> 6/1/2009 1:45:30 PM -> 01
>
> 6/15/2009 1:45:30 PM -> 15

---

> "H"
>
> The hour, using a 24-hour clock from 0 to 23.
>
> More information: The "H" Custom Format Specifier.
>
> 6/15/2009 1:45:30 AM -> 1
>
> 6/15/2009 1:45:30 PM -> 13

---

> "HH"
>
> The hour, using a 24-hour clock from 00 to 23.
>
> More information: The "HH" Custom Format Specifier.
>
> 6/15/2009 1:45:30 AM -> 01
>
> 6/15/2009 1:45:30 PM -> 13